# Better suggestion for name "Closed Loop Automation"

Tags: navigation, menu, text, taxonomy, sidemenu

I am adding a new feature that enables closed-loop-automation. This involves creating an object that has a trigger and an action. Whenever the trigger happens, the associated action will be taken. Both trigger and action are some sort of scripts that run on a set of data.

Now I am looking for a better alternative for closed-loop-automation text to be displayed on the menu. I have thought about CLA, Actions. But somehow it does not capture the entire closed loop system concept.

Are there any better suggestions for "*Closed Loop Automation*"? Any fancy name would also help for marketing as well. Thanks!

Comment: Is there also an open-loop-automation function in your app/website/thingy?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that within your software you do not have an *Open Loop Automation* feature, you could shorten the label by removing the *Closed Loop* part.

The best sense from the context given would be something along the lines of **Enable Automation**.

However the term automation is very vague. Since what you are describing

> This involves creating an object that has a trigger and an action.

is an event, I would suggest terms like **Enable Event** or **Create Event**.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

"Open" vs. "closed" loop are very system-centric terms but it's hard to judge in the abstract without knowing about the real life scenario or domain. Those details influence what is appropriate.

"Automation" alone may suffice, as long as there's no open loop version of automation.

It just depends on the context and the user audience you're designing this for. What makes sense to them? Do they care about the closed- vs. open-loop distinction?